# Bulkify Apex Methods Using Collections In Methods false positive?

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting, checkmarx, bulkification

Why would a simple method like

```
@RemoteAction
global static Custom__c upsertCustom(Custom__c custom){
    upsert custom;
    return [SELECT Id, Name, CalculatedField__c FROM Custom__c WHERE Id = :custom.Id];
}
```

cause a

> Apex Methods Using Collections In Methods Bulkify

warning in the [Checkmarx Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner)?

Note: Not sure if it matters, but from the javascript the method `upsertCustom` is not being called within a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a false positive. In most cases a method that accepts a single record and performs a DML Operation on it might be called in a loop, and hence be considered non-bulk-safe. However, considering this method is a `RemoteAction`, that concern seems misplaced.

Comment: without RemoteAction, if I am sure a method is not being called inside a loop, can a false positive be given for it?

Comment: Probably. I assume you'd just have to prove it.